# How can I change the build system of python.sty from Python2 to Python3?

Tags: packages, python, build-system

I am using the `python.sty` package, downloaded [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/python?lang=en). I found the default build path is to use Python2.7:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}
\begin{python}%
import sys
print (sys.version)
\end{python}%
\end{document}
```

This tex gave me `2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]`

My question is can I change the Python version, which `python.sty` is using ,to Python 3.5?

Comment: what does `python -v` on the command line say?

Comment: @yo' It should be `-V` :P On my OS, python is version 2.7.9 while python3 is version 3.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `python` is hard-coded in the package. You can make it to call `python3` with a patch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\endpython}{python }{python3 }{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{python}
import sys
print (sys.version)
\end{python}
\end{document}
```

In the log file we find

```
runsystem(cat  jay.py | python3 > jay.py.out 2> jay.py.err)...executed.
```

and this is the PDF output

[image]

An extended version where you can switch from one version to the other; the `\setpython` command obeys the normal scoping rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\endpython}{python }{python\python@version\space}{}{}
\newcommand{\setpython}[1]{%
  \if3#1\relax
    \def\python@version{3}%
  \else
    \def\python@version{}%
  \fi
}
\makeatletter
\setpython{2} % initialize

\begin{document}
\begin{python}
import sys
print (sys.version)
\end{python}

\bigskip

\setpython{3}

\begin{python}
import sys
print (sys.version)
\end{python}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this way is so cool! You are replacing the `python` with `python3` in a higher level.

Comment: @JayWong The extended version is even better, as it allows you to switch between the two versions in the same document. You may also consider PythonTeX, for many more functionalities (but requires a separate call of `pythontex`).

Comment: Yeah, I am reading some examples of pythontex. It looks really powerful, and it has already been installed. Hmm but currently, your solution is totally enough for my project.

Answer (score 1):

Make a directory in `TEXMFHOME` for your adapted version:

```bash
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/python3/
```

Move there

```bash
pushd $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/python3/
sed -e 's+\(ProvidesPackage{python\)\(}\[\).*\(.*Python in LaTeX\)+\13\22016/06/17 v0.21-3 \3 modified for Python3 by JW+' -e 's+\(\\immediate\\write18{.*\| python\)\( > \\jobname\.py\)+\13\2+' $(kpsewhich python.sty) > python3.sty
popd
```

and then say

```latex
\usepackage{python3}
```

Note that this is entirely untested - I know as close to zilch about Python as makes no odds, but `python` on my system just is 3.5.1.